# How to root a S4 google play edition on mac?

Tags: rooting, samsung-galaxy-s-4, macos

I have been cracking my head open trying to find a good guide to root my Google Play Edition Samsung. I have sought out YouTube videos that utilize motochopper and terminal and while I manage to get Superuser installed, I don't have root access. I've also tried forums but most of them just use Windows. Is there anyone who's done this and can instruct me on how to do it?

Comment: Do you have adb set up on your computer?

Comment: No. There is an adb file on the folder but i have no idea what its for or how to set it up

Comment: I've posted an answer below that will hoepfully help. I would encourage you to read up on ADB, recoveries, firmware etc in the meantime. I said it below, but the feeling of bricking a device is horrible! Sorry had to delete the whole answer, I misrad, I didn't realise it was Google Play edition. That's far less easy.

Comment: It seems like you would be better off getting to a Windows PC and using ODIN and CFAutoRoot. Heimdall is the equivalent of ODIN for mac, but it seems like the Google Edition / CfAutoRoot / Heimdall do not work together.

Answer (score 0):

Before You Root Android on Mac OS X

1. Make sure you backup all your data.
2. Backup MMS/SMS
3. Backup Call details & restore app
4. Backup other stuff with my most recommended Titanium Backup & MyBackup Root
5. Also make sure that your phone is charged at least 90% so that it does not goes of in the middle of the Root Android on Mac OS X process. Also be sure that your computer is set of with the antivirus and firewalls, the cable with the specific drivers must be ready

Please Download Droid Easy Root v7d.zip Now Extract this Zip Folder to specific destination.

```
Set USB debugging Enabled for your Phone, To do so go to Settings-Applications-Development, and check the box for “USB debugging”.
Connect your Phone with The PC.
Don’t select file sharing or tethering mode.Just be in the Charging Only State.
Open terminal and change the path to the folder we just extracted that is “Droid Easy Root v7d”.
Now execute the “run_to_root_your_droid3.sh” present there to open the one click root tool.
Its Almost Done, Now just follow the On screen Instructions and wait for the rooting process to take place.
Also during this the Phone will Reboot many times so just keep calm and let Root your android device.
You have Rooted Your Android.
```

**OR**

Please Download Droid Easy Root v7d.zip. . Now Extract this Zip Folder to specific destination.

```
After Download if the Zip File doesn’t unzips itself then double click and open it, A folder of same name will be opened.
Find the path of the new folder, To get it Right Click on the File and then File Info, the file path appears on the left side.
Open Terminal (applications>utilities>terminal)
Change directory to the new folder (the file path you found earlier) the following file path is an example:cd /Users/yourname/Downloads/droid_easy_root_v7
Press enter now the terminal will change to the new directory.
Remember always entering these commands – These Commands are case sensitive and you need to take care of your Caps Lock.
On your DX, be sure USB debugging is turned on, If not So then enable it by going settings>applications>development>USB debugging and tick mark the check box.
Now Connect the DX to your Mac and select Charge Only from the notification bar. Don’t Go For tethering or File Sharing Mode.
While still in terminal and now in the proper directory type :./run_to_root_your_droid3.sh
Now Press Enter. And Keep Upper Case and Lower case Letters in Consideration.
Now Just Follow The On screen Instructions And In this process the Phone will Reboot for 3 times.
Enjoy Your Rooted Android Through Mac OS X.
```

**Downloads**  [Droid easy root v7d](http://www.filecrop.com/droid-easy-root-v7d.html)